# Pacman Game KeyListener

Tags: java, keylistener, pacman

I have 2 classes for the beginning of a pacman game and I am really confused by how the key listener or keybindings work. I have methods for move up, down, right and left. I have spent hours trying to figure i out and it wont call regular methods and the components are confusing me. Could someone please help to show me how to get the end result of the arrow keys calling methods? i have the code below, but I took out all of my key tests.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class GUI {
JPanel myPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(50, 50, 1, 1));
int[][] myLabels = new int[50][50];

//Set Game Black
public int[][] setBlack(int[][] arrayLabels){
    myLabels = arrayLabels;
    for (int i = 0; i < myLabels.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < myLabels[0].length; j++) {
            JLabel black = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("black-square.jpg"), JLabel.CENTER);
            myLabels[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }
    return myLabels;
}


//get panel any time changes are made to array
public JPanel getPanel(int[][] arrayLabels){
    myLabels = arrayLabels;
    for (int i = 0; i < myLabels.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < myLabels[0].length; j++) {
            JLabel black = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("black-square.jpg"), JLabel.CENTER);
            JLabel pacman = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("pacman.png"), JLabel.CENTER);
            if(myLabels[i][j] == 1){
                myPanel.add(black);
            }
            if(myLabels[i][j] == 2){
                myPanel.add(pacman);
            }
        }
    }
    return myPanel;
}

//moves pacman up
public int[][] moveUp(int[][] arrayLabels){
    myLabels = arrayLabels;

    for (int i = 0; i < myLabels.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < myLabels[0].length; j++) {
            if(myLabels[i][j] == 2){
                myLabels[i][j] = 1;
                myLabels[i-1][j] = 2;
            }
        }
        }
    return myLabels;
}

//=========
//moves pacman up

public void setLabel(int[][] arrayLabels){
    myLabels = arrayLabels;
}

public int[][] moveUpKey(){

    for (int i = 0; i < myLabels.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < myLabels[0].length; j++) {
            if(myLabels[i][j] == 2){
                myLabels[i][j] = 1;
                myLabels[i-1][j] = 2;
            }
        }
        }
    return myLabels;
}
//////===========================
//moves pacman down
public int[][] moveDown(int[][] arrayLabels){
    myLabels = arrayLabels;

    for (int i = 0; i < myLabels.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < myLabels[0].length; j++) {
            if(myLabels[i][j] == 2){
                myLabels[i][j] = 1;
                myLabels[i+1][j] = 2;
            }
        }
        }
    return myLabels;
}

//moves pacman right
    public int[][] moveRight(int[][] arrayLabels){
        myLabels = arrayLabels;

        for (int i = 0; i < myLabels.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < myLabels[0].length; j++) {
                if(myLabels[i][j] == 2){
                    myLabels[i][j] = 1;
                    myLabels[i][j+1] = 2;
                }
            }
            }
        return myLabels;
    }

    //moves pacman left
            public int[][] moveLeft(int[][] arrayLabels){
                myLabels = arrayLabels;

                for (int i = 0; i < myLabels.length; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < myLabels[0].length; j++) {
                        if(myLabels[i][j] == 2){
                            myLabels[i][j] = 1;
                            myLabels[i][j-1] = 2;
                        }
                    }
                    }
                return myLabels;
            }



}
```

Game Class:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import java.util.*;



public class Game {


   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final GUI gui = new GUI();


        JFrame f = new JFrame("Frame Test");


        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(50, 50, 1, 1));

        int[][] labels = new int[50][50];



      JLabel black2 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("black-square.jpg"), JLabel.CENTER);
      JLabel pacman2 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("pacman.png"), JLabel.CENTER);
      panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(50, 50, 1, 1));

                labels = gui.setBlack(labels);
                panel = gui.getPanel(labels);




                labels[10][10] = 2;



                //labels = gui.moveUp(labels);

                panel.removeAll(); 
                panel = gui.getPanel(labels);
                panel.repaint();






                //labels[i][j]

       //.revalidate();


       //do the thing 
        f.setContentPane(panel);
        f.setSize(1000, 1000);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);



   }


}
```

Comment: Both key bindings and `KeyListener` are contextual.  They should be registered against the component you want to recieve event notitifcation about

Answer (score 2):

Basically, `myPanel` is acting as the core container for your game.

This is probably the best candidate for registering key bindings to...

Create a constructor for your `GUI` class.  Within this constructor, you will need to register your key bindings, for example...

```
public GUI() {

    InputMap im = myPanel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    ActionMap am = myPanel.getActionMap();

    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0), "up");
    am.put("up", new AbstractAction() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            moveUp(myLabels);
        }
    });
    // Register other key strokes...

}
```

ps- I don't know why your movement methods need the `JLabel[][]` parameter, as `myLables` is accessible to these methods anyway, but that's just me...

Make sure you have a read through [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details